# how to implement A* in a 20x20 table?

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

A 20x20 matrix is given in which ones stand for barriers and zeros are permitted to be passed. Given the coordinates of start and the goal, I should find a way to the goal using A*. But I don't know what to consider as h(n) and what for g(n).

Here is an instance of a possible area (matrix) the start point is in red and the goal is blue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

g(n) is the length of the path from the start and current position

h(n) is an estimate which must be minoring the cost from current position to the goal for example the Manathan distance :
With (x1,y1) the coordinates of goal.

```
abs(y-y1)+abs(x-x1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`g(n)` = Number of hops (i.e. boxes traversed on the grid) taken in the path from the start node to `n`

and `h(n)` can be Euclidean distance from `n=(nx,ny)` to the goal `g=(gx,gy)` i.e.

```
 h(n)=sqrt((nx-gx)^2+(ny-gy)^2)
```